# what's an alternative to make dynamic links (other than javascript) to make them google-crawable?

Tags: javascript, seo

I have a page where in some links are built when the page loads using a javascript function makes link, depending on the current url of the page. On click, an ajax call loads the new page.

How do I make these links google-crawlable (since google doesn't crawl javascript links)?

As an example I'd like to mention github. So when you open, say,  https://github.com/pennersr/django-allauth all the links inside are already loaded with their respective links, depending on the current URL. When you view-source, you can see the links there. Whereas you just see a javascript function in the view-source had the links been made through javascript. I don't think these values are being passed from the back-end as well.

What's a possible solution to do this?

Comment: Have you placed the resulting URL's in your sitemap?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about SEO

Comment: I cant build my full site map, since the urls can't be crawled as they are javascript functions.

Comment: marked as duplicate?! I dont see a reason actually. I think that question is about page transitions and a one page application structure! This one is totally about SEO and making your links google crawlable if you already have smooth transitions!

Answer (score 1):

This is a common issue in Single Page Applications or applications that use intensively JavaScript and AJAX.

First of all you need to create unique URL for this actions in JavaScript, so the crawler can at least "hit these actions". If you execute a function in JavaScript, but your URL doesn't change, Google will never be able to know that there's something happening there. 
Normally AJAX URL's are written like this:

```
http://www.foo.com!#jsAction
```

Google crawler will be able to crawl this URL but probably the page that will get back  will be blank since is the JavaScript code the responsible to render all the content.

This is why the crawler will change the '!#' for the word _escaped_fragment_ when calling your server. So the previous URL being requested by the crawler would be:

```
http://www.foo.com?_escaped_fragment_=jsAction
```

With this new keyword in the URL we can determine in the server that the request comes from a crawler, and here is when the magic starts. 
Using a headless browser like [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/) we can execute the JavaScript code in the server and return the fully rendered HTML to the crawler request. This is one of the approaches that Google suggest in their guidelines.

So basically the point is to determine which type of request you get and execute different code depending if the query string contains _escaped_fragment_.

This link from Google might help you to point you to the right direction: https://developers.google.com/webmasters/ajax-crawling/

Hope it helps!

Comment: That's an ugly hack from before we had the history API. (Github, referenced in the question, uses the history API and not this hack).

Comment: Can you explain how to make a website crawlable with the History API? I really do not know how to do it.

Comment: How can the server know that the request is from a crawler when using pushState?

Comment: No! The point of pushState is that you use *real* URLs that resolve to *real* pages so you don't go anywhere near `_escaped_fragment_`